Amazon v3 javascript SDK not returning any data when working with IAMClient
Including some other bits and pieces i have the following code to create a new IAM user with the amazon v3 javascript sdk.
const client = new IAMClient({
            credentials: {
                accessKeyId: "accesskey",
                secretAccessKey: "secretkey",
            },
            region: this.region, // eu-central-1
        });
const command = new CreateUserCommand({
   UserName: "MyTestUser",
});
const response = await client.send(command);

From the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/iam/command/CreateUserCommand/) it seems like i should be getting a javascript object that should look something like this:
{
  "User": {
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Bob",
    "CreateDate": "2013-06-08T03:20:41.270Z",
    "Path": "/",
    "UserId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
    "UserName": "MyTestUser"
  }
}

But what i am actually getting is this (seems like its only the metadata):
{
   "httpStatusCode":200,
   "requestId":"9111ea22-0d64-44f8-9c2c-225424f77fb3",
   "attempts":1,
   "totalRetryDelay":0
}

The funny thing about that is, that in the Network Tab of Chromes developer tools the data i want seems to be there.
The response the sdk receives from amazon looks like this:
<CreateUserResponse xmlns="https://iam.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-05-08/">
  <CreateUserResult>
    <User>
      <Path>/</Path>
      <UserName>MyTestUser</UserName>
      <Arn>arn:aws:iam::525123112340:user/MyTestUser</Arn>
      <UserId>AIDAXUVAXXXXXXXXCHWWD</UserId>
      <CreateDate>2024-04-15T21:42:12Z</CreateDate>
    </User>
  </CreateUserResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>99d79e72-fa7a-4fed-843a-e63b7feb6e22</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</CreateUserResponse>

package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-iam": "^3.515.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.515.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.523.0",
    ...
}

Reinstalling and updating the packages brought no change whatsover (not that i thought that that would help) and to be honest im stuck at the moment.
Please not that i switched from V2 to V3 recently and did not notice the issue until now so im pretty new to V3.
Any advice is highly appreciated.
